# Rails project not detected by gitlab SAST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, gitlab

I have a rails project hosted on gitlab and I would like to use the SAST gitlab app to run code analysis on my code. When I run SAST on my machine, It works fine:

```bash
docker run \
    --env SAST_BRAKEMAN_LEVEL=3 \
    --volume "$PWD:/code" \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/sast:11-0-stable" \ 
    /app/bin/run /code
```

**However, when the gitlab runner executes it, It doesn't detect my application as a rails project and so I have this error**:

```
docker run --env SAST_BRAKEMAN_LEVEL=3 --volume "$PWD:/code" --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/sast:$SP_VERSION" /app/bin/run /code
2018/08/22 17:45:43 Copy project directory to containers
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [bandit] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [bandit] Project not compatible
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [brakeman] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [brakeman] Project not compatible
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [find-sec-bugs] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [find-sec-bugs] Project not compatible
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [find-sec-bugs-gradle] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [find-sec-bugs-gradle] Project not compatible
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [find-sec-bugs-sbt] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [find-sec-bugs-sbt] Project not compatible
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [flawfinder] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [flawfinder] Project not compatible
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [go-ast-scanner] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [go-ast-scanner] Project not compatible
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [phpcs-security-audit] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [phpcs-security-audit] Project not compatible
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [security-code-scan] Detect project using plugin
2018/08/22 17:45:43 [security-code-scan] Project not compatible
No compatible analyzer can be found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 3
```

Here the gitlab-ci.yml I use

```
### ...
sast:
  stage: lint
  tags:
    - my-runner
  image: docker:stable
  allow_failure: true
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
  script:
    - export SP_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_SERVER_VERSION" | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1-\2-stable/')
    - echo $SP_VERSION $PWD
    - ls
    - docker run
        --env SAST_BRAKEMAN_LEVEL=3
        --volume "$PWD:/code"
        --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/sast:$SP_VERSION" /app/bin/run /code
  artifacts:
    paths: [gl-sast-report.json]
```

```

Notice that the gitlab runner I use is running on my own machine, I don't use a shared gitlab runner available on gitlab.

Any idea what is going  wrong?

Comment: Are you on GitLab 11.0 or later? The generated value for $SP_VERSION will vary depending on your GitLab version, whereas the local version you showed corresponds specifically to GitLab 11.0 (11-0-stable).

Comment: I have printed the SP_VERSION variable in the CI pipeline and I got 11-1-stable. That's why, I tested locally on my machine with this docker image tag